# Find the number of subsets

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory

> For any positive integer $n$, let $ν_3(n)$ denote the largest integer $k$ such that $3^k$ divides $n$. Find the number of subsets $S$ (possibly containing $0$ or $1$ elements) of $\{1, 2, \ldots, 81\}$ such that for any distinct $a, b \in S$ with $a > b$, the number $ν_3(a − b)$ is even.

Here was the solution to this question: In general, for $n \geq 0$, we let $s_n$ denote the number of subsets $S$ of $\{1,2,\ldots,3^n\}$ such that $2 | ν_3(a-b)$ for any distinct $a, b \in S$, and $t_n$ the number of subsets $S$ with $2 \nmid ν_3(a - b)$ for any distinct $a, b \in S$. Clearly $s_0 = t_0 = 2$, and for $n \geq 2$, we have $s_n = t^3_{n-1}$ while $t_n = 3s_{n-1} − 2$.

> Can anyone explain why those two equalities are true?

Comment: Every $0$- or $1$-element subset $S$ vacuously satisfies the required condition, “that for any distinct $a, b\in S$...” because there are never distinct $a$ and $b$ in $S$. Any statement of the form “For any [whatever], something.” is true if there are no [whatever]s.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First observe that $\nu_3(n)$ answers the question “When written in base $3$, how many zeroes does $n$ end with?” Then it is easy to see that for $a\neq b$, $\nu_3(a-b)$ is even if and only if $a$ and $b$, when written in base $3$, differ in the final digit, or end in the same two (but not the same three) digits, or end in the same four (but not five) digits, and so on.

Similarly, $\nu_3(a-b)$ is odd if and only if $a$ and $b$, when written in base $3$, have the same rightmost digit but differ in the penultimate digit, or have the same three, but not four, right most digits, and so on.

Equivalently, let $t(a,b)$ be the length of the longest tail of digits in base $3$ where $a$ and $b$ match; $t(a,b)=\nu_3(a-b)$.

Call a set an $s_n$-set if it is one of the ones you count to get $s_n$, and call a set a $t_n$-set if it is one that you count to get $t_n$. An $s_n$-set (*resp.* a $t_n$-set) is exactly a subset of $\{1,\dots,3^n\}$ with the property that for distinct $a,b\in S$, $t(a,b)$ is even (*resp.* odd).

In particular, note that the elements of a $t_n$-set (if there are any) must all have the same final digit in base 3.

Now we will show that when $n \geq 2, s_n = t^3_{n−1}$ with a counting argument.

Suppose you have an $s_n$-set $S$ for some $n$. For $i=0,1,2$, let $S_i\subseteq S$ be the subset of those elements of $S$ that have rightmost digit $i$ in base 3. Then let $T_0$, $T_1$, and $T_2$ be obtained from the $S_i$ by removing every element’s final digit. Formally, $T_i=\{\frac{s-i}{3}:s\in S_i\}$. It is not hard to see that each $T_i$ is a $t_{n-1}$-set. (Think about the function $t(a,b)$ described earlier.)

Now suppose you have any three (not necessarily distinct or nonempty) $t_{n-1}$-sets, $T_0$, $T_1$, and $T_2$. Append a $0$ digit to every element of $T_0$, a $1$ digit to every element of $T_1$, and a $2$ digit to every element of $T_2$, and let $S$ be the union of these results. It is not hard to see that $S$ is an $s_n$-set.

These transformations between single $s_n$ sets and triples of $t_{n-1}$ sets describe a one-to-one correspondence between the collection of $s_n$-sets and the collection of all triples of $t_{n-1}$-sets, therefore when $n \geq 2, s_n = t^3_{n−1}$

The other equation (which should read $s_n = 3t_{n-1}-2$) is easier to show. Given an $s_{n-1}$-set $S$, create sets $T_i$ for $i=0,1,2$ by appending $i$ to the elements of $S$. For a given non-empty $S$, these $T_i$ are distinct, because their elements’ final digits distinguish them, and given distinct non-empty sets $S$ and $S'$, the resulting $T_i$ and $T'_i$ are all different ($S$ or $S'$ can be obtained by removing all final digits). If $S=\emptyset$, the $T_i$ are identical (and empty). The observation that every $t_n$ set is such a $T_i$ for exactly $S_{n-1}$-set confirms that for $n\ge2$, $s_n = 3t_{n-1}-2$. The $- 2$ is needed because the empty $T_{n-1}$ set yields only $1$, not $3$, $S_{n}$-sets in this way.